# What's the hydraulic loss of this overflow?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, hydraulics

Consider the following image:

[image]

what we see is are upright pipes into a water vessel, upper end of the pipes above the max. water level. Water is pumped into the pipes from below. We need to consider the friction losses in the pipe(s), the geodetic height (in this case 64.45 m) but also some losses from the overflow, or dissipation. What are they?

The closes approximations (and why they dont fit IMO):

- The end of the pipe is a short round weir - but the flow conditions are very different fomr typical weir situations
- sharp edged exit - but the jet is water into air, the change of medium should matter (or does it?).

I've looked at several books on hydraulics like Idelchik and searched online and came up with nothing so far.